# Material2: Strange behavior using md-hint

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm facing a problem with `md-hint` of [**Material2#input**](https://material.angular.io/components/component/input).

I want to show a *hint* based on condition, so I'm doing something like this:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" [formControl]="anyCtrl">
  <ng-container *ngIf="myCond">
    <md-hint *ngIf="otherCond" align="end">* Just a hint</md-hint>
  </ng-container>
</md-input-container>
```

But it looks weird, as you can see in [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1FUZDsH9VHaxSPTDLWzS), the `md-hint` isn't being displayed correctly at the bottom of the input and aligned in the end as I specified.

To my surprise it doesn't happen if I use `*ngIf` only in`md-hint` (without wrapping it with `ng-container`) [also described in **plunker** ~second example~].

**The problem:**

I can't use the `*ngIf` directly in `md-hint` because my real condition is that:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data[key]?.data | async as resolvedData">
  <md-hint *ngIf="resolvedData[key]?.length === 0" align="end">Hint</md-hint>
</ng-container>
```

So, as you can see if I'd convert it the whole expression to `*ngIf` it would be as follows:

```
<md-hint *ngIf="data[key]?.data | async?[key]?.length === 0" align="end">Hint</md-hint>
```

Which one throws an exception accusing template parse errors (**async?[key]**), because the [**Safe Navigation Operator**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) **only** accepts *dot* syntax, and those keys that I'm working on are dynamic, so I must use *bracket* syntax. That's why I'm wrapping into 2 `*ngIf` as you could see above.

Finally, the question is: Why does the style of `md-hint` acts different if I have a simple `ng-container` wrapping it? Is it a bug?

Thanks in advance.